# Ubuntu showing 2 different versions

Tags: 14.04, 13.04

Hi I have upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.10 still its showing me 14.04 in "About this Computer" menu. While in login screen its showing 16.10. and windows key not opening search Dash. I tried to setup shortcut from keyboard shortcut still its not working. I am not aware of all features of Ubuntu so its big problem or need some small fixes?

[image: Login screen showing 16.10 version]

[image: About this computer menu]

Comment: Open terminal and type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`....let me know

Comment: Executed command 1 package upgraded still showing same thing.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity` and reboot

Comment: Sorry I ran this command still its showing same thing.

Comment: Dont know any other solutions... reinstall ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for help. I am not facing any functional issue right now. So not planning to reinstall it and hopefully won't face any issue in future as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

How did you upgrade to 16.10? Did you have any problem during the upgrade?

Can you please post your "sudo lsb_release -a" output?

By the way, a package named "distro-info-data" has been upgraded today. I thought it might be related. If you're sure you're using yakkety and just see the old version displayed in the info page, I guess you should be fine nonetheless.

Comment: ****-3559:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.10
Release: 16.10
Codename: yakkety

Comment: I haven't got any problem during upgradation. All works perfectly.